# Error connect to Spring-boot-Rsocket (Auth JWT) from web-client RSocketWebSocketClient

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket

The connection to server with spring-boot client works good:

```
public RSocketAdapter() throws IOException {
    requester = createRSocketRequesterBuilder()
    .connectWebSocket(URI.create("ws://localhost:7878/"))
    .block();
}
private RSocketRequester.Builder createRSocketRequesterBuilder() {
    RSocketStrategies strategies = RSocketStrategies.builder()
    .encoders(encoders -> encoders.add(new Jackson2CborEncoder()))
    .decoders(decoders -> decoders.add(new Jackson2CborDecoder()))
    .dataBufferFactory(new NettyDataBufferFactory(PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT))
    .build();
    return RSocketRequester.builder().rsocketStrategies(strategies);
}

public Mono<HelloToken> signIn(String principal, String credential) {
    return requester
            .route("signin.v1")
            .data(HelloUser.builder().userId(principal).password(credential).build())
            .retrieveMono(HelloToken.class)
            .doOnNext(token -> {
                accessToken = token.getAccessToken();
            })
            .onErrorStop();
}
```

And server receives such frame:

[Correct byte frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bygr1.png)

But the same request from web-client:

```
authSocketReactiv = () => {    
    const maxRSocketRequestN = 2147483647;    
    const keepAlive = 60000;
    const lifetime = 180000;
    const dataMimeType = 'application/json';
    const metadataMimeType = 'message/x.rsocket.authentication.bearer.v0';
    
    var client = new RSocketClient({
      serializers: {
        data: JsonSerializer,
        metadata: JsonSerializer,
      },
      setup: {
        dataMimeType,
        keepAlive,
        lifetime,
        metadataMimeType
      },
      transport: new RSocketWebSocketClient({
        url: 'ws://localhost:7878'                
      },Encoders)
    });

    // Open the connection
    client.connect().subscribe({
    onComplete: socket => {
      socket.requestStream({
        data:{
          'user_id': '0000',
          'password': 'Zero4'
        },
        metadata:'signin.v1'

      }).subscribe({
        onComplete: () => console.log('complete'),
        onError: error => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        onNext: payload => {
          console.log('Subscribe1');
        },
        onSubscribe: subscription => {
          console.log('Subscribe');
          subscription.request(2147483647);
        },
      });
    },
    onError: error => {
      console.log(error);
    },
    onSubscribe: cancel => {
     
    }
  });
```

Forms the incorrect frame and fall with “metadata is malformed ERROR” :

[Error byte frame from web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8X8T.png)

What encoding or buffering options should be used here? Thanks for any tips and suggestions.

Comment: Responded on GitHub: https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/discussions/228

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely going to want to work with composite metadata and set your `metadataMimeType` to `MESSAGE_RSOCKET_COMPOSITE_METADATA.string`.

The important bit is going to be the routing metadata, which is what tells the server how to route the incoming RSocket request.

I haven't dug through the server example code you linked on StackOverflow, but just by looking at your example code, you would supply the routing metadata with your `requestStream` as so:

Also, the [example project](https://github.com/feuyeux/kio#design) you listed though references `signin` as a `request/response` so you actually don't want `requestStream`, but `requestResponse`.

```js
socket
  .requestResponse({
    data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({
      user_id: '0000',
      password: 'Zero4'
    })),
    metadata: encodeCompositeMetadata([
      [MESSAGE_RSOCKET_ROUTING, encodeRoute("signin.v1")],
    ]),
  })
```

You will likely want to use `BufferEncoders`, as shown in this [example](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/blob/cdfa824513ae58c5ef8abb14c3754c99199296b8/packages/rsocket-examples/src/CompositeMetadataExample.js). And additionally, I believe you should not use `JsonSerializer` for the metadata, but instead `IdentitySerializer`, which will pass the composite metadata buffer straight through, rather than trying to serialize to and from JSON.

You may still run into some issues, but I suspect that this will get you past the `metadata is malformed ERROR` error.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Grate thanks for the detailed advices. According to directions, this complined solution works for my case:

```
  getAuthToken = () => {    

    const maxRSocketRequestN = 2147483647;    
    const keepAlive = 60000;
    const lifetime = 180000;
    const dataMimeType = APPLICATION_JSON.string;
    const metadataMimeType = MESSAGE_RSOCKET_COMPOSITE_METADATA.string;

    var client = new RSocketClient({
      serializers: {
        data: IdentitySerializer,
        metadata: IdentitySerializer,
      },
      setup: {
        dataMimeType,
        keepAlive,
        lifetime,
        metadataMimeType
      },
      transport: new RSocketWebSocketClient({
        url: 'ws://localhost:7878'                
      },BufferEncoders)
    });
    
    client.connect().then(
      (socket) => {
        socket.requestResponse({

          data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({
            user_id: '0000',
            password: 'Zero4'
          })),
          metadata: encodeCompositeMetadata([
            [MESSAGE_RSOCKET_ROUTING, encodeRoute("signin.v1")],
          ]),

        }).subscribe({ 
         onComplete: (data) => console.log(data),
         onError: error =>
            console.error(`Request-stream error:${error.message}`),
        });
      },
      
      (error) => {
        console.log("composite initial connection failed");
      }
    );
```